# SPA that needs to use Symfony2 Backend

Tags: php, apache, symfony, single-page-application

i've got the following problem. I've got a Symfony2 installation running. Everything is fine with it, but now i have a SPA next to my Symfony2 Installation. The SPA needs to call the Symfony2 Installation to get some data via JSON.

We use Apache as our Server. We got Symfony2 to run. But now we've got the Problem that the SPA should be adressable by a specific URL.

Example:

- www.symfyon2.installation/ <- Symfony2 Installlation
- www.symfony2.installtion/editor <- the SPA

Im honestly stuck with the configuration for Apache Virtualhosts. Does someone have a recommendation for that specific scenario, that does'nt involve much Boilerplate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place following .htaccess in subfolder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  #Disable rewriting
  RewriteEngine Off

</IfModule>
```